# Static Toast routine for debugging

Tags: android, debugging

I'm trying to debug some code on an obscure Android device that does not have an ADB (Android debug bridge) driver for Android Studio so I cannot step through code on the device with the Android Studio debugger so I'm debugging blindly.

So I thought I would use an old-fashioned "printf" strategy by inserting little Android toasts with various debug information in my code where I needed them.   Some of the code I'm calling this from are static and some aren't.

I made a "make toast" routine

```
// make a Toast I can use for debugging
private static void makeToast(String msg) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(thisActivity, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 200);  // x offset , y offset
    toast.show();
}
```

The "this" activity is declared thusly:

```
 private static PlyListActivity thisActivity = null;
```

And initialised in OnCreate ...

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //We need another instance to avoid a static reference
        selBox = new SelBoxListener();  //was final SelBoxListener 
        RemoteControlActivity.curContext = this;
        thisActivity = this;
 . . .
```

Here's an example of it being called . . .

```
public static void updateBillboard(final int resColor, final String imsg2) {
    //Are we created yet?
    if (plyBillboard != null) {
        plyBillboard.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                plyBillboard.setTextColor(resColor);
                plyBillboard.setText(imsg2);
            }
        });
    } //fi
   //!! thisActivity.finish();
    makeToast("in UpdateBillboard");
}
```

No toast pops up.   If I un-comment out the call to *finish()* it exits the Activity, thus confirming I am executing the code. . .

So what am I doing wrong and how do I get my toasts to appear?

**Edit:**  one responder suggested I needed to put the call to *makeToast()* inside the runnable so it would be called.   But that's why I noted that if I uncomment the call to *finish()* it causes to Activity to exit.   Indeed, if I place a call to *finish()* inside *makeToast()* it does the same thing, so the call to *makeToast()* IS being executed.

Comment: what happens if you don't set the gravity? does it show?

Comment: Nothing.  If I comment that line out nothing different seems to happen; there's no visible toast.

Comment: Nevermind, gravity is unlikely the issue. Your code seems mostly correct to me (I'd use WeakReference for myActivity variable), does it show if you show the Toast inside (for example) the onCreate method?

Comment: Yes, it works in onCreate().  (thanks for the suggestion!)  So how do I make something that works everywhere?

Comment: I just posted an answer, with the code you provided I think that the issue is that you're calling a UI method inside a non UI thread, Toast requires to be called from the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the method updateBillboard is not running inside the UI Thread, so one way to make it work is to use a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html). For example:

```
private static Handler mHandler;
@Override
onCreate(Bundle...) {
    super.onCreate(...);
    mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage) {
            String message = (String) inputMessage.obj;
            makeToast(message);
        }
    }
}   

updateBillboard(...) {
    ...
    Message message = mHandler.obtainMessage(0, "Hello");
    message.sendToTarget();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you look at the definition of Runnable "
When an object implementing interface Runnable is used to create a thread, starting the thread causes the object's run method to be called in that separately executing thread."

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
             Log.d("Thread", "I am on UI thread");
          showToastHere();
      } 
    });
```

Comment: But if I **un**comment out the finish(), as I explained in my question,  that gets executed, so it's not a matter of the toast not getting called. In fact I can achieve the same thing by putting the finish() inside the _makeToast()_ routine, so I know it's getting called.

Comment: use Runnable inside a Handler. Its then on the ui thread. Otherwise its not on ui thread and hence u cannot show toast when its not on a UI thread

Comment: Your use of "its" is ambiguous.   Are you saying the even when when the toast is being called, nothing is displayed because the toast code is executing in the wrong (not a UI-) thread?   So if I want to use toast as a general-purpose debugging display (i.e., like printf) can I place a runnable inside my _makeToast()_ routine?

Comment: No do not call runnable inside makeToast. But what I am saying is Runnable cannot call Toast as it is on a seperate thread. Create a handler and call runnable inside that and then execute Toast. Then that Toast is on Ui thread. Try something like above